# TableViewCell delegation with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I have ViewController (MainVC) with TableView filled with custom cells. They have enabled or disabled star sign.

[image]

When user taps on cell he navigates to separate ViewController (DetailedVC). There is button there which switches featured status for the object. I want to use delegation pattern for this case - so when user comes back to MainVC object featured status is also updated.

**I created protocol**

```
protocol FeaturedDelegate {
   func toggleFeatured (cell : CustomCell) 
}
```

**Made MainVC conform to it**

```
class MainVC : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, FeaturedDelegate {
     func toggleFeatured (cell : CustomCell) {
        //toggle featured status for cell
     }
}
......
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomCell = ...
    cell.featuredDelegate = self
    return cell
}
```

In this case the delegate is inside cell. But I need ti to be in DetailedVC. What should I do next?

Comment: **object featured status is also updated** <- what do you mean by it?

Comment: when user taps on button with featured sign in DetailedVC and makes item featured - i want it to be also marked as featured in tableview cell

Comment: You actually saying `star` is used to mark as a feature.  User can `enable/disable` the feature from list (that image you posted in quest) and also from the detail screen( when user navigates by selecting that feature). Is Im getting you right?

Comment: yes, you got it right. Need to mention that I can enable/disable the feature only from detail screen.

Comment: Ok and in this screen (shown in image) is only for showing list. NOw it is right?

Comment: yes, screenshot only shows custom cells in MainVC

Comment: Ok first tell me where you storing this list??

Comment: objects are inside array in MainVC

Comment: Take one array in app delegate and keep update that array instead of taking detail VC. Use same array in listVC.

Comment: In this case I should reload TableView. I want to handle it using delegation pattern

Comment: Still you need to reload the table. Check this -> https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-delegation--cms-23901

Comment: If i have 1000 rows in my table and user taps on the last row to get DetailedVC, if I reload TableView, when he gets back to MainVC he will see first row. Do you understand it?

Comment: Whenevr you made change in the array and you wanted to reflect that change in tableview then you have reload it. No other option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a protocol in DetailVC.

//**DetailVC**

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func toggleFeatured (indexOfCell index: Int, isEnable: Bool)
}
```

When star value is change than call this delegate function.

```
delegate?.toggleFeatured(indexOfCell: indexOfCell, isEnable: isEnable)
```

In Masterviewcontroller's tableview didselected function set delegate

//**MasterViewController**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detailVC = DetailVC()/* get detalVC object */

    detailVC.delgate = self
    detailVC.indexOfCell = indexPath.row

    //show detailvc
}
```

If you don't want to reload complete tableview then you can reload cell only.

```
extension MasterViewController: SecondViewControllerDelegate {
   func toggleFeatured(indexOfCell index: Int, isEnable: Bool) { 

   let object = array[index]
   // Logic to enable or disable star for for object

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
   }
}
```

**MOST IMPORTANT**

Don't forgot to make the delegate **weak**. weak keyword won't let the retain count increase by one hence retain cycle don't generate and memory leak problems won't come. if we don't write and any keyword then it will be strong by default which increase the retain count and create retain cycle(Deadlock).

And We need to make protocol class type because weak keyword can be use only with class type protocol. check protocol declaration, it inherited **class**

```
class DetailVC {
   weak delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

Check out this video to understand memory leak and fix it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sp8qEMY9X6Q